# Declare Array of Object in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to declare:

```
type ArticleModel = {
    _id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Then in my class:

```
public models: ArticleModel[];
```

Where models should be as you may have guess an array of ArticleModel.

But node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js throws:

```
error TS2322: Type 'Object[]' is not assignable to type '{ _id: number; name: string; }[]'.
  Type 'Object' is not assignable to type '{ _id: number; name: string; }'.
    Property 'id' is missing in type 'Object'..
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't get confused with id and _id, it's just a typo in here...

Answer (score 7):

Ok my bad, I was re-declaring the variable later as:

```
let models:Array<Object> = [];
```

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

if you want to instantiate your object array when you create your class, you can do this:

```
public models: ArticleModel[] = [];
```

This is in place of doing it in the class constructor.